# error : "DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am using this function to create two-way interactions for all features (using sickitLeran function PolynomialFeatures ), but i got this error : "DataFrame constructor not properly called!" 
my code is :

```
def add_interactions(DataFrame):

    combos=list(combinations(list(DataFrame.columns), 2))
    colnames=list(DataFrame.columns) + ['-'.join(x) for x in combos]

    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
    DataF = poly.fit(DataFrame)
    print(DataF)
    DataF.columns=colnames
    DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(DataF)

    noint_indicies=[i for i, x in enumerate (list((DataFrame == 0).all())) if x]
    DataFrame = DataFrame.drop(DataFrame.columns[noint_indicies], axis=1)
     return DataFrame

T = add_interactions(X)

   the traceback of the error: 

   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-61-790b132c4f1d> in <module>()
    1 poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2,interaction_only=True, include_bias=False)
   2 DataFrame = poly.fit(X)
    ----> 3 DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data = DataFrame)
    4 print(DataFrame.head(3))

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, 
     data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
     402                                          dtype=values.dtype, 
     copy=False)
     403             else:
    --> 404                 raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not 
    properly called!')
    405 
    406         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

    ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: The error tells that you create DataFrame with wrong parameters. Can you please post traceback or add row number, which produces the error? Or code of a row where you initiate X variable? 
Also check other related StackOverflow questions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DataFrame+constructor+not+properly+called)

Comment: @Alex K  i added the traceback

Comment: poly.fit(X) returns PolynomialFeatures instance, not a DataFrame, so you cannot pass it to DataFrame constructor.